# Outlook Explorer Object Giving 'NULL' Attachment Selection

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, email-attachments

I want a **selected** attachments from below window.

I have used `Explorer.AttachmentSelection` method. But its not giving me any selection.

How to achieve it?

[image]

Comment: What is the complete code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AttachmentSelection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.attachmentselection) object contains a read-only collection of attachments that are selected in an item that is in the active inspector or the active explorer. Use the [ActiveExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.activeexplorer) method of the Application class which returns the topmost `Explorer` object on the desktop. An Explorer that represents the topmost explorer on the desktop is returned. You may get `Nothing` or `Null` if no explorer is active. So, you may get `null` if no attachments is selected in the view.

I'd suggest click on any attachment in the view and validate how the code is working. You should get the attachment instance selected in the `Outlook view`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have debug my code & I came to know that it can be achieve through `control.Context`. I have casted result to `AttachmentSelection`.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to select an attachment in the preview pane (so that "Back to message" button becomes visible) for `Explorer.AttachmentSelection` collection to contain anything.

Comment: Yes i have tried that & I was getting selection. But i have a add-in that is to be feature in both window (Explorer & Window that openes on double click of mail). Thanks.

Comment: Inspector object exposes the same property - `Inspector.AttachmentSelection`.